# Giving an example of a family of sets considering finite and denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My Question Reads:

Give an example, if possible, of a family $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$of sets such that

a) Each set $A_i$ is finite and and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ is denumerable

b) Each set $A_i$ is finite and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ is finite

I am not too sure how to go about finding a family of sets. Does this mean picking all natural numbers or all integers, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) How about let $A_i = \{i\}$ for all $i$? Then $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty}A_i = \mathbb{N}$

b) How about let $A_i = \{1\}$ for all $i$? Then $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty}A_i = \{1\}$

Comment: $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ is the family. My answer defines what each of these $A_i$ are, thus defining a family of sets. Does that make sense?

Comment: Another way to say a "family of sets" would be to say a "set of sets," it is just more common to say "family of sets" in a situation like this because it is in some ways less confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I get that it would be like a group of sets together.

Comment: Oh ok. So in my example for a), When I say that $A_i = {i}$, I mean that $A_1 = {1}, A_2 = {2}, A_3 = {3}, $ and so on.

Comment: Oh....yes this is what I meant. I was not seeing that. But how do you know i will be numbers 1,2,3..etc. Are you defining i to be in the natural numbers?

Comment: well, yes, it is for all $i$ in the natural numbers. I assumed that because you wrote $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ in the question.

Comment: it is also apparent that $i$ is for all natural numbers if you look at the indices on the union symbol

Comment: Well this was just how my answer was worded. I am not sure if the A_1,A_2, etc is supposed to restrictive to the natural numbers. But it works in this case nonetheless right?

Comment: Yes, this answers the question.

Comment: Typically in mathematics, when we are asked to find something "denumerable," it is assumed that it is "infinite and denumerable" because if it was finite, we would have just said that it was finite.

Comment: My definition for denumerable is equivalence to the natural numbers. Then for b are you saying A_1=A_2=A_3.....=1?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Then does that not work for both cases?

Comment: well, $\{1\}$ is finite, so I wouldn't say that it is denumerable, there is no bijection between $\{1\}$ and the natural numbers

Comment: yes, I think so.